# Searching links with DOMAssistant

Tags: javascript

I'm using [DOMAssistant](http://www.domassistant.com/) library to search for specific links and then replace them with some other links, but I am  unable to search links.

I want to search all links that contain `http://www.google.com/`, and I want it to return these links:

- `http://www.google.com/123`
- `http://www.google.com/"24234`
- `http://www.google.com/example`

I do not want to get it with id:

```
($("#id").elmsByAttribute("href");)
```

I'm new to js and DOMAssistant library, can anybody help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://semat.com.sa">semat.com.sa</a> | <a href="http://google.com">google.com</a> | <a href="http://google.com?111">google.com?111</a> | <a href="google.com?id=33edd">google.com?id=33edd</a> | <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> | <a href="http://sematsystems.com">sematsystems.com</a>


<script>$('a[href*="google"]').css({"color":"red"});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way for search multiple domains

```
<script>$('a[href*="google"], a[href*="semat"]').css({"color":"red"});</script>
```

Comment: but i want it to get from array

Comment: Should be a comment. And you should be more specific about what you want. **What** do you want to get form an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = ['a[href*="google"]','a[href*="semat"]'];

$.each(x,function(index) {
alert(x[index]);
});
```